# NGINX Load balancing config for multiple websites

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have a NGINX load balancer, with two webservers behind it. Both of them have similar content - hosting similar apps on different domains. Right now my config looks like this:

```
upstream  foosite  {
    ip_hash;
    server   11.222.33.444;
    server   555.666.777.888;
}

upstream  barsite  {
    ip_hash;
    server   11.222.33.444;
    server   555.666.777.888;
}

upstream  bazsite  {
    ip_hash;
    server   11.222.33.444;
    server   555.666.777.888;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foosite.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://foosite;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name barsite.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://barsite;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bazsite.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bazsite;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Here are the quiestions:

1) Will this config work for multiple top level domains ? Like foosite.com, foosite.org, foosite.net etc ?

2) How can I enable subdomains for all these webistes ? For instance test.foosite.com, admin.foosite.com without making the whole thing too verbose ?

3) It looks like this config can be written wiht less lines of code, how can I merge all 3 upstream definitions into 1, how can I merge 3 server blocks into 1 ?

Thanks in advance.